# limit and indicator function

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose E is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with finite measure. Prove that $$ \lim_{h\to 0^{+}} \frac{m(E\cap [x,x+h])}{h}=\chi_E(x)$$

I tried to prove this by rewrite the left hand side into integral form.

$$ \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h} \chi_E  dm$$ Inside the limit the average value function. But I have no idea about the next step. Is it alway true that $\lim_{h\to 0+} \frac{1}{h} \int_{x}^{x+h} f(t)dt=f(t)$
Can someone help me?

Comment: Check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem

Comment: That is the statement of FTC, which does not apply in the above case. The proof proceeds in a different direction.